# Resolve TNSNAMES 2 DBs

Tags: database, oracle, listener

I'm new to this community and i would like to get some help on configuring 2 databases.

So my problem is:
Need help on understanding what im doing wrong on the TSNAMES.ora

I have 2 DBhomes everything was working fine till last day i had to make some local tests and i executed the following sintax, after restarting services everything is messed up.

```
ALTER system SET MEMORY_MAX_TARGET = 10 G SCOPE = spfile ; 
ALTER system SET MEMORY_TARGET = 8 G SCOPE = spfile ;
```

Using sqlplus i can only connect to the DB2 and DB1 is not working, it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor
```

if i tnsping to the db1 it shows me

```
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 30-SEP-2020 15:25:50

Copyright (c) 1997, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = DEMO)))
OK (0 msec)
```

If i do a LSNRCTL status it shows me the DBHome2 ora file

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 30-SEP-2020 15:36:45

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                30-SEP-2020 15:00:31
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 36 min. 13 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\Oracle\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-7O2CVPP\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cmms" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cmms", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cmmsXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cmms", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

So i need to see here instance demo as well as status Ready to work i guess.

So it seems to be some resolving problem to get the right folder.

I would like some help if you please.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: My guess is that the `DEMO` database can't start up because it can't get enough memory at startup.  Have you looked at the alert log for the `DEMO` database?  Does it show that the database is starting up successfully?  Or does it show that it is encountering errors?

Comment: In the log the last results about the error is this:

<msg time='2020-09-30T16:05:14.574+02:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='DESKTOP-7O2CVPP'
 host_addr='fe80::5829:74d6:4c7d:60ab%22' pid='16496'>
 <txt>TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
 </txt>
</msg>

Comment: When you restarted the database after making the parameter changes, there would be a whole bunch of messages written to the alert log.  Do those indicate that the database started successfully?  Or that it is encountering errors?

Comment: The database doesnt work, i tryed to use Sql Dev and it shows me the same error 

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 Vendor code 12505

I dont understand pretty well about the alert log can you explain what do i need to do to check that info ?

Thanks

Comment: After you made the parameter changes and restarted the database, there would be a bunch of messages in the alert log.  You'd need to go to that point in time.  I will wager that rather than showing that the database started successfully, you'll see a number of errors indicating that the database couldn't start because there wasn't enough memory.

Comment: You're looking at network client/listener logs, when you need to be looking at the database's alert log on the database server. The listener doesn't know of the service because the database most likely didn't start. You need to look at the right log to find out why it didn't start correctly.

Comment: The thing is i have 2 Dbhomes which one do i check ?
And how do i check if the database is running ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you even have two homes?  If the two databases are running the same version and patch level, there is zero reason to have a separete home for each.  Likewise you only need one listener.  The name of the alert log will be 'alert<sid>.log.  So just use your OS's search to find all 'alert*.log'.

Comment: Ok so the file is here https://pastebin.com/ZL1Qbh4q i dont quiet understand the error message inside.
So i have tryed 2 times to fix the error and reduce the ammount of memory available.

ALTER SYSTEM SET memory_max_target=4G SCOPE=SPFILE;
ALTER SYSTEM SET memory_target=4G SCOPE=SPFILE;

How can i restart the database if it is off ?

Thanks in advance for your time